# Countdown button angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i created a countdown feature where it only counts if the user is in the current window of the browser, and it works very well, the only problem is when i insert my code in angularjs controller. It stops working, above i leave my code to everybody have a idea what is wrong.

js:

```
var span = angular.element('#count');
        var counter = 30;
        var timer;

        var startTimer = function() {
            // do nothing if timer is already running
            if (timer) return;

            timer = setInterval(function() {
                counter--;
                if (counter >= 0) {
                    span.innerHTML = counter;
                }
                // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
                if (counter === 0) {
                    alert('this is where it happens');
                    stopTimer();
                }
            }, 1000);
        };

        var stopTimer = function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        };

        var onBlur = function() {
            stopTimer();
        };

        var onFocus = function() {
            startTimer();
        };

        var onLoad = function() {
            startTimer();
        };


        angular.element(window).load(onLoad);
        angular.element(window).blur(onBlur);
        angular.element(window).focus(onFocus);
```

html:

```
<a  class="btn btn-medium btn-orange" href="">
            In<span id="count">30</span></a>
```

Comment: Do use `$interval` instead of `setInterval`, which will take care of digest cycle to keep binding in sync & then use `$interval.cancel(interval)` to `clearInterval`, Additionally `angular.element('#count')` should be `angular.element(document.getElementById('count'))` as `jQLite` doesn't support `selector` based query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use non angular functions like setTimeout or setInterval inside angular code. These functions won't be part of the digest cycle and your view won't change.

Take a look at this example for creating a timer with angular.

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/refresh-div-angularjs-interval/

Comment: hi, this link is broken